# Printing a specific column field using sqlAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, Case and Motion. I have the following query:

`queries = db.session.query(Case.summary, Case.motion_id, Motion.id, Motion.summary).filter(Case.motion_id == Motion.id)`

If I want to print the Case.summary, I can do the following which I have tested to work:

`for query in queries: logging.error(query.summary)`

But if I want to print the summaries of both Case and Motion (ie, Case.summary and Motion.summary), how should I write my for loop?

I have tried:

`logging.error(query.summary + " | " + query.motion.summary)`

and

`logging.error(query.summary + " | " + query.motion_summary)`

but both didn't print motion summary. Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn\`t be  `query.Motion.summary`? Capital letter.

Comment: @Mihai I tried with a capital M for motion, but it still didn't work. The error was "AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'Motion' "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force SQLAlchemy to include duplicate columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511379/how-do-i-force-sqlalchemy-to-include-duplicate-columns)

Comment: While the duplicate target is using the expression language rather than the ORM, the solution is the same - you must label at least one of the `summary` columns in the query so that they are distinguishable, for example `Case.summary.label('case_summary')` and use the label in your logging statement: `logging.error('%s | %s, 'query.case_summary, summary)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution/workaround for my question. You will need to use labels, which label the column with another name. It is like writing the 'AS' in SQL:

`Select id AS motion_id FROM motion`

In terms of SQLAlchemy, write query in views.py as such:

```
queries = db.session.query(Case.summary.label('case_summary'), Case.motion_id.label('case_id'), Motion.id.label('motion_id'), Motion.summary.label('motion_summary').filter(Case.motion_id == Motion.id)
```

Now my columns are called and labelled as 'case_summary', 'case_id', etc.

So I can log by writing:

```
for query in queries:
    logging.error(query.case_summary)
    logging.error(query.motion_summary)
```

Hope this helps!

Thank you @snakecharmerb for direction.